# Ramanujan summation on convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series

From Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation

I saw this formula
$f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+\cdots=-\frac{f(0)}{2}+i\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(it)-f(-it)}{e^{2\pi t}-1}dt$.

If we let $f(x)=x$, we have $1+2+\cdots=-\frac{1}{12}$.

I want to know that if we can use the trick to compute the value of a convergent series.

For example, if I let $f(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)^{2}}$, can I use the above formula to show that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}=\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}$?